# Bind Button ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, button, data-binding, contextmenu

I want to show Context menu on button click so I did the following

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="4" 
        Width="30" 
        Height="30" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="1,5,0,5" 
        Click="btn_Click" 
        ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="false">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="popup" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding FavoriteProductCollectionViewModelIns}" 
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>/

private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

The problem the binding doesn't work and the context is empty, any idea how to fix the binding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` is placed within a `Popup` which has its own visual tree.

As a result, the ContextMenu is not part of the visual tree and is not be able to resolve anything outside the ContextMenu popup.

To fix this, you could explicitly set the `ItermsSource` property as shown below:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popup.ItemsSource = FavoriteProductCollectionViewModelIns;
    popup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the Popup's [PlacementTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placementtarget.aspx) property as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939632/relativesource-and-popup).

XAML:

```
<Button
    x:Name="FavoriteProductButton"
    Width="30"
    Height="30"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Margin="1,5,0,5"
    Click="btn_Click"
    ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="false">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="popup"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding FavoriteProductCollectionViewModelIns }"
                     DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                     DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FavoriteProductCollectionViewModelIns = new List<FavoriteProductViewModel>
        {
            new FavoriteProductViewModel {Name = "Menu 1"},
            new FavoriteProductViewModel {Name = "Menu 2"}
        };
        DataContext = this;
        popup.PlacementTarget = FavoriteProductButton;
    }

    public class FavoriteProductViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public List<FavoriteProductViewModel> FavoriteProductCollectionViewModelIns { get; set; }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```